# TF broadcast along first axis

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, array-broadcasting

Say I have 2 tensors, one with shape `(10,1)` and another one with shape `(10, 11, 1)`... what I want is to multiply those broadcasting along the first axis, and not the last one, as used to

```
tf.zeros([10,1]) * tf.ones([10,12,1])
```

however this is not working... is there a way to do it without transposing it using `perm`?

Comment: You shoud do `tf.zeros([10,1])[...,None] * tf.ones([10,12,1])`.

Comment: @V.M and add a `None` for every dimension that they differs (like if the first `ones ` had shape `[10,11,12,13,1]` i should add many None right?)?

Comment: You need to follow this- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above example, you need to do  `tf.zeros([10,1])[...,None] * tf.ones([10,12,1])` to satisfy  broadcasting rules: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules

If you want to do this for any random shapes, you can do the multiplication with the transposed shape, so that the last dimensions of both the matrices match, obeying broadcasting rule and then do the transpose again, to get back to the required output,

```
tf.transpose(a*tf.transpose(b))
```

Example,

```
a = tf.ones([10,])
b = tf.ones([10,11,12,13,1])

tf.transpose(b)
#[1, 13, 12, 11, 10]
(a*tf.transpose(b)) 
#[1, 13, 12, 11, 10]
tf.transpose(a*tf.transpose(b)) #Note a is [10,] not [10,1], otherwise you need to add transpose to a as well.
#[10, 11, 12, 13, 1]
```

Another approach is to expanding the axis:

```
a = tf.ones([10])[(...,) + (tf.rank(b)-1) * (tf.newaxis,)]
```

Comment: yes the double transposition is what i'm currently doing, but seems pretty computationally heavy

Comment: I have added another a way to expand the axis.

Comment: mh I like it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the broadcasting rules, but you can prevent broadcasting by doing it yourself. Broadcasting takes effect if the ranks are different.
So instead of permuting the axes, you can also repeat along a new axis:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import einops as ops

a = tf.zeros([10, 1])
b = tf.ones([10, 12, 1])

c = ops.repeat(a, 'x z -> x y z', y=b.shape[1]) * b
c.shape
>>> TensorShape([10, 12, 1])
```

Comment: however I should determine how many new axis to add, where broadcasting does it automatically